# Application Insights blade greyed out for Azure function v3

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

Why is the Application Insights blade greyed out for an Azure function **v3**?

The functions itself running .NET Core v3.1.
There is one function with Event Hub listener and a couple of durable functions with time trigger.

[image]
`APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` variable is set with a correct key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are based on Linux OS, you will face this:

[image]

This is a problem with the Function UI. You can go to your trigger, and select this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then it will be ok.

Comment: Thank you! It works now. What a messy user interface btw. It is mostly very intuitive in Azure but definitely not this time.